# Eliminate each duplicate value from columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table including some rows. If the row in its column is duplicate value, I don't want it. Let me exemplify.

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
1     X     Q    9
2     Y     W    9
3     Z     E    9
3     X     R    9
3     Y     T   null
2     Z    null null
```

I expect (ordering is negligible)

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD
1     X     Q    9
2     Y     W    null
3     Z     E    null
null  null  R    null 
null  null  T    null
null  null  null  null
```

I would write for each column almost same select clauses but I don't think it is efficient.

Comment: In SQL a table is a relationship, so each **row** represents a tuple of related values. Regardless of the storage (row or columnar format) a table has the same semantic. What you try to do brakes the relationships between values of a single row and is meaningless. You need to use another model to store or represent your data. To answer your question we need a rule how to relate deduplicated values

Comment: *ordering is negligible* - explain the significance of this statment with regard to your desired output - with your data set there is no way to guarantee the relationships of each row.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it (but I wonder about the purpose of it ):

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT 1 as ColA, 'X' as ColB,'Q' as ColC,'9' as ColD
   UNION
   SELECT 2,'Y','W',9
   UNION
   SELECT 3,'Z','E',9
   UNION
   SELECT 3,'X','R',9
   UNION
   SELECT 3,'Y','T',null
   UNION
   SELECT 2,'Z',null,null)

select 
   AA.ColA,
   BB.ColB,
   CC.ColC,
   DD.ColD
from 
   (select ColA, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ColA) RowA from (
       select DISTINCT ColA from CTE)  A) AA
FULL JOIN
   (select ColB, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ColB) RowB from (
       SELECT DISTINCT ColB from CTE) B ) BB
   ON BB.RowB = AA.RowA
FULL JOIN 
   (select ColC, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ColC) RowC from (
       SELECT DISTINCT ColC from CTE) C ) CC
   ON CC.RowC = AA.RowA
FULL JOIN
   (select ColD, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ColD) RowD from (
       SELECT DISTINCT ColD from CTE) D ) DD
   ON DD.RowD = AA.RowA
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=02c52adb4f9480ba7a8f2ee79e9b0d45)

Answer (score 0):

You want to suppress values when selecting data from the table? This is typically not done in SQL, but in the app displaying the data.

But if you want to, you can do this in SQL (using windw functions). For this to work you'd have to specify the order in which to select the rows. You say, you don't care about the order, so in below query I simply generate some row number we can base this on:

```
with numbered as
(
  select t.*, row_number() over order by (newid()) as rn
  from mytable
)
select
  case when count(*) over (partition by cola order by rn) = 1 then cola end as a,
  case when count(*) over (partition by colb order by rn) = 1 then colb end as b,
  case when count(*) over (partition by colc order by rn) = 1 then colc end as c,
  case when count(*) over (partition by cold order by rn) = 1 then cold end as d
from numbered
order by rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by colA order by ordcol) = 1 then colA end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colB order by ordcol) = 1 then colB end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colC order by ordcol) = 1 then colC end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colD order by ordcol) = 1 then colD end)
from tablename t;
```

If you don't have such a column, then it becomes tricker.  You can generate one:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as ordcol
      from tablename t
     )
select (case when row_number() over (partition by colA order by ordcol) = 1 then colA end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colB order by ordcol) = 1 then colB end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colC order by ordcol) = 1 then colC end),
       (case when row_number() over (partition by colD order by ordcol) = 1 then colD end)
from t;
```